# Unable to Shutdown/Restart/suspend linux system

Tags: linux, arch-linux

Question is for all suspend/restart/shutdown but description and logs are for last suspend only.

I am unable to suspend my system. I do `systemctl suspend` and monitors goes off but the cpu keeps running. Then I can't resume system again and have to do a force shutdown. Happened with both nvidia535 and nouveau drivers.

Important Logs from gnome-logs

```
Jan 17  8:35:03 PM systemd-sleep: Failed to lock home directories: Unknown object '/org/freedesktop/home1'.
Jan 17  4:22:48 PM kernel: usb 1-8: 3:1: cannot get freq at ep 0x84
Jan 17  4:22:47 PM rtkit-daemon: dbus_message_get_unix_user() failed: The connection does not exist
Jan 17  4:22:45 PM sddm-helper: gkr-pam: unable to locate daemon control file
Jan 17  4:22:29 PM kernel: usb 1-8: 3:1: cannot get freq at ep 0x84
Jan 17  4:22:29 PM kernel: 
Jan 17  4:22:26 PM kernel: x86/cpu: SGX disabled by BIOS.
```

All logs

```
Jan 17  8:35:03 PM kernel: PM: suspend entry (deep)
Jan 17  8:35:03 PM systemd-sleep: Performing sleep operation 'suspend'...
Jan 17  8:35:03 PM systemd-sleep: Performing sleep operation 'suspend'...
Jan 17  8:35:03 PM systemd-sleep: Failed to lock home directories: Unknown object '/org/freedesktop/home1'.
Jan 17  8:35:03 PM systemd: Starting System Suspend...
Jan 17  8:35:03 PM systemd: Starting System Suspend...
Jan 17  8:35:03 PM systemd: Reached target Sleep.
Jan 17  8:35:03 PM kernel: r8169 0000:03:00.0 enp3s0: Link is Down
Jan 17  8:35:03 PM NetworkManager: <info>  [1705503903.5217] device (enp3s0): state change: disconnected -> unmanaged (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jan 17  8:35:03 PM systemd: Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.
Jan 17  8:35:03 PM NetworkManager: <info>  [1705503903.2005] device (enp3s0): state change: activated -> deactivating (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jan 17  8:35:03 PM systemd-logind: The system will suspend now!
Jan 17  8:35:02 PM rtkit-daemon: Failed to look up client: No such file or directory
Jan 17  7:54:02 PM systemd: systemd-hostnamed.service: Deactivated successfully.
Jan 17  7:54:00 PM rtkit-daemon: Failed to look up client: No such file or directory
Jan 17  7:53:32 PM systemd: Started Hostname Service.
Jan 17  7:53:30 PM rtkit-daemon: Failed to look up client: No such file or directory
Jan 17  7:13:01 PM kernel: perf: interrupt took too long (3144 > 3136), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 63600
Jan 17  7:12:52 PM rtkit-daemon: Failed to look up client: No such file or directory
Jan 17  6:18:38 PM kernel: perf: interrupt took too long (2509 > 2500), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 79500
Jan 17  6:18:08 PM rtkit-daemon: Failed to look up client: No such file or directory
Jan 17  4:37:30 PM systemd: Finished Cleanup of Temporary Directories.
Jan 17  4:37:30 PM rtkit-daemon: Failed to look up client: No such file or directory
Jan 17  4:34:20 PM systemd: systemd-hostnamed.service: Deactivated successfully.
Jan 17  4:34:09 PM rtkit-daemon: Failed to look up client: No such file or directory
Jan 17  4:33:51 PM dbus-broker-lau: Activation request for 'org.freedesktop.Avahi' failed: The systemd unit 'dbus-org.freedesktop.Avahi.service' could not be found.
Jan 17  4:33:50 PM systemd: Started Hostname Service.
Jan 17  4:33:39 PM rtkit-daemon: Failed to look up client: No such file or directory
Jan 17  4:33:14 PM systemd: Started User preferences database.
Jan 17  4:33:14 PM udisksd: Acquired the name org.freedesktop.UDisks2 on the system message bus
Jan 17  4:33:14 PM systemd: Started Disk Manager.
Jan 17  4:33:14 PM udisksd: udisks daemon version 2.10.1 starting
Jan 17  4:33:14 PM systemd: Starting Disk Manager...
Jan 17  4:32:59 PM rtkit-daemon: Failed to look up client: No such file or directory
Jan 17  4:24:29 PM systemd: Started PipeWire PulseAudio.
Jan 17  4:24:28 PM rtkit-daemon: Failed to look up client: No such file or directory
Jan 17  4:23:03 PM systemd: systemd-hostnamed.service: Deactivated successfully.
Jan 17  4:23:00 PM systemd-timesyn: Initial clock synchronization to Wed 2024-01-17 16:23:00.753279 IST.
Jan 17  4:22:57 PM rtkit-daemon: Failed to look up client: No such file or directory
Jan 17  4:22:56 PM systemd: Started Daemon for power management.
Jan 17  4:22:55 PM (sd-pam): pam_warn(systemd-user:setcred): function=[pam_sm_setcred] flags=0x8004 service=[systemd-user] terminal=[] user=[sddm] ruser=[<unknown>] rhost=[<unknown>]
Jan 17  4:22:55 PM systemd: Started Portal service.
Jan 17  4:22:55 PM xdg-desktop-por: No skeleton to export
Jan 17  4:22:55 PM rtkit-daemon: Supervising 4 threads of 2 processes of 1 users.
Jan 17  4:22:55 PM systemd: Reached target Exit the Session.
Jan 17  4:22:55 PM dbus-broker: Dispatched 172 messages @ 2(±8)μs / message.
Jan 17  4:22:55 PM systemd: Closed PipeWire Multimedia System Sockets.
Jan 17  4:22:55 PM gnome-keyring-d: asked to register item /org/freedesktop/secrets/collection/login/2, but it's already registered
Jan 17  4:22:55 PM systemd: Starting Portal service...
Jan 17  4:22:48 PM wireplumber: <WpPortalPermissionStorePlugin:0x60a632f0af20> Failed to call Lookup: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.portal.Error.NotFound: No entry for camera
Jan 17  4:22:48 PM systemd: Started sandboxed app permission store.
Jan 17  4:22:48 PM pipewire: [0:00:23.411006570] [662] [1;32m INFO [1;37mCamera [1;34mcamera_manager.cpp:284 [0mlibcamera v0.1.0
Jan 17  4:22:48 PM kernel: usb 1-8: 3:1: cannot get freq at ep 0x84
Jan 17  4:22:48 PM at-spi2-registr: SpiRegistry daemon is running with well-known name - org.a11y.atspi.Registry
Jan 17  4:22:48 PM systemd: Started dbus-:1.20-org.a11y.atspi.Registry@0.service.
```

Answer (score 1):

From my understanding of the documentation on Kernel.org, suspend doesn't mean "cpu stops doing any work whatsoever". ["processors ... spend time in their deepest idle states"](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/pm/sleep-states.html). Though that might just "mean power is being lightly supplied to CPU, but even low level code is not being executed". Also worth reading the descriptions of the different types of suspend states, identifying which one you are entering, and trying to determine if that might be the cause of your issues?

Also worth looking into if you may be getting a false positive on the fact that the CPU is running at all. How exactly are you checking this, is it something to do with the logs that I'm missing?

As another route for debugging, take a look at this [thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/490719/how-does-systemctl-suspend-work), it might be possible that your `sleep.conf` file (if one exists) is configured incorrectly to send something to `/sys/power/state` that you shouldn't be.

Comment: On most PCs (which default to ACPI S3 state or "s2ram"), it _does_ mean the CPU stops completely. The "deepest idle states" mode (Intel's S0ix or "s2idle") is a much newer feature; it's common on 'modern' laptops, but many people avoid it on Linux because it's really not as good as advertised. I'm not sure any desktops use S0ix/s2idle – it makes less sense because often they have a separate PSU fan that can't really turn off unless the system goes to S3. (The middle state in that doc, "standby", is ACPI S1 which I haven't seen being used since early 2000s.)

Comment: ah, I see. Still technically could be the case if OP is somehow being put into those new suspend modes, but if Linux avoids it, then it's probably unlikely. Thanks for the note, I'm mostly unfamiliar with some of the lower level stuff, just posting my results from researching docs and forums online.

Comment: Linux uses whatever the firmware suggests as default, but 1) users manually change it back to S3 via systemd (the file `/sys/power/mem_sleep` shows which mode is currently [chosen]); and 2) often the UEFI firmware settings screen offers an option like "Sleep mode: Windows|Linux" or "Modern Standby: yes|no", where choosing "Windows" enables S0ix/s2idle while choosing "Linux" forces S3.